# Delta between query execution time and Java query call to finish

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

**Context**

- Our container cluster is located @ us-east1-c
- We are using the following Java library: google-cloud-bigquery, 0.9.2-beta
- Our dataset has around 26M rows and represents ~10G
- All of our queries return less than 100 rows as we are always grouping on a specific column

**Question**

We analyzed the last 100 queries executed in BigQuery, these are were all executed in about 2-3 seconds (we analyzed this by calling **bq --format=prettyjson show -j JOBID**, end time - creation time).

In our Java logs though, most of the calls to **bigquery.query** are blocking for 5-6 seconds (and 10 seconds is not out of the ordinary). What could explain the systematic gap between the query to finish in the BigQuery cluster and the results being available in Java? I know 5-6 seconds isn't astronomic, but I am curious to see if this is a normal behaviour when using the Java BigQuery cloud library.

I didn't dig to the point where I analyzed the outbound call using Wireshark. All our tests were executed in our container cluster (Kubernetes).

**Code**

```
QueryRequest request = QueryRequest.newBuilder(sql)
                .setMaxWaitTime(30000L)
                .setUseLegacySql(false)
                .setUseQueryCache(false)
                .build();

QueryResponse response = bigquery.query(request);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the code briefly here:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigquery/BigQueryImpl.java

It appears that there are multiple potential sources of delay:

- Getting query results
- Restarting (there are some automatic restarts in there that can explain the delay spikes)
- The frequency of checking for new results

It sounds like looking at Wireshark would give you a precise answer of what is happening.